# After Upgrade to 22.04 unable to access remote desktop via VNC legacy (was working on 20.04)

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I was able to use vncviewer in the past to this machine with no problems.
After the upgrade I configured teh Remote Desktop Sharing correctly in the Settings.
When I try to connect to the machine I get:

```
vncviewer 192.168.20.19
Connected to RFB server, using protocol version 3.8
Performing standard VNC authentication
Password: 
Authentication successful
```

But no screen. Apparently everything is working, but I get no screen back to the machine that is using the vncviewer. Tried everything that I could find /think of:

X11, Wayland, rdp, vnc, no firewall, ...

If I stop the remote with:

```
systemctl --user stop gnome-remote-desktop.service
```

I get:

```
vncviewer 192.168.20.19
Connected to RFB server, using protocol version 3.8
Performing standard VNC authentication
Password: 
Authentication successful
vncviewer: read: Connection reset by peer
```

BTW, the above connections were made in loopback (the vncviewer is being executed in the 192.168.20.19 machine).

I need to use "barrier" to this machine and so RDP is out of the question, although I've used it to try and debug the situation, but I get the same behaviour: connects but no display back.

I have another 22.04 machine that was upgraded and the VNC is working fine.

So, at this moment I'«m completely at a loss. Any help is appreciated, namely to try and debug why this is happening on this machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Yep. I am. When I connect I used the Ubuntu over X. Even already tried with the WaylandEnable=false  on /etc/gdm3/custom.cof